# How can I show an image as a background of a div?

Tags: html, css

inside home.html :

```
<div id="footer">
    this is working!!!
</div>
```

in css file:

```
#footer
{
    height: 70px;
    background-image:url('footer.png'); 
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I check the url of image again & again.. But I cannot see the image as background in footer div. what is the reason. please help me

Comment: Maybe your css file is in another directory then image is

Comment: This is not something we can help you with, its likely just the image being in the wrong directory as the syntax is fine

Comment: Is any of your CSS working, if yes, is the image inside the directory with the .css file?

Comment: Where is your image located from the root point of view? I keep my images at : assets/img/lorem.jpg

Comment: Open your Browser's inspector (usually F12), then the console, reload the page. Any error messages?

Comment: @Cedric Reichenbach if image is not loaded he will see error messages in console definitely :)

Comment: @Morpheus Maybe he's using a blank image... :P

Answer (score 5):

The syntax seems to be fine

Put the path relative to the css file

e.g.
if your files are located as

```
WEB-INF
|     | css
|     |      your.css
|     | images
|     |      footer.png
```

Then use

```
 background-image:url('../images/footer.png');
```

You could use firebug to look for the correct path, you can edit the url by putting `../../images` and once the image is visible update your css file with the same data.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is fine basically.

The path to the image is probably wrong.
Try `../` to go up one folder from your css file or `/yourpath/footer.png` to start from the root folder.